# how use the eventchannel of flutter for desktop on windows?

Tags: windows, flutter

I want to use event channel notify the flutter, but I can't find any example about event channel for desktop(windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mothed channel is duplex mode, dart invoke native funtion by "channel" + "funtion" , Similarly, native invoke dart function by the same way.

1、using the cmd:

```
flutter create -t plugin --platforms=linux,macos,windows window_to_front
```

2、find the function：

```
RegisterWithRegistrar
```

3、using “channel” in “RegisterWithRegistrar” function：

```
channel->InvokeMethod("foo", nullptr, nullptr)
```

4、registe the "channel" and "function" in dart:

```
var channel = MethodChannel("test2");
channel.setMethodCallHandler((call) {
  switch(call.method) {
    case "foo": {
      //String msg = call.arguments["msg"];
      print("Native invoke Flutter susscess，params：${call.arguments}");
      //return "success";
    }
  }
```